# Template Builder: better suggestion needed

Tags: java

I want to make a custom template builder (template will generate report). I want to provide a drag and drop facility, so that user can build their own template for generating report. e.g. if user choose header part, header part will appears with data.

This I want to achieve using Java. Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do not build it yourself. There are a lot of these kind of tools already available. Open source: JasperReports. Eclipse BIRT.

Comment: These tools are for developer e.g JasperReports. Eclipse BIRT. but for enduser how is user going to create his own template, without the developer. Any suggession on that point.

Answer (score 0):

Some buzzwords comming in my mind is something like XSLT to generating report. The XSLT sheet would be your template and can be created through your own DSL definition. Just look for these two buzzwords especially for DSL. Hope I could help a little bit.